# Query Optimization : Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty brand new to Elasticsearch and am looking to perform some sort of two steps query on one index. Indeed, the items in the index have what we call a cli_ID attribute, which I would like to pre-filter the data on, and then perform an embedding similarity calculation (that could take some time) only on the items that match the first query.

Plus I would need to retrieve the scores associated with the embedding calculation exclusively.

I have implemented a solution using the post-filter option of Elasticsearch, however, it does not provide the score associated with the second query (embedding similarity calculation)

```
query_body = {
"query": {"wildcard": { "client_ID" : "*"+cli_ID+"*" }},
"post_filter": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        /: query for the embedding calculation goes here. :/
      ]
    }
  }
```

}

This is a test using the post_filter option but definitely does not fit our use case completely.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650870/function-score-inside-the-post-filter-query-elasticsearch)

This link indicates that the post-filter can't provide the score using a filter option.

So my question is a little open, but I would really appreciate some guidance towards whatever solution that :

Helps me prefilter the items in the index by client-ID
Then compute the embedding similarity on those items
Let me access the scores that are produced in the second query;
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: you could try to use a Script score query ([link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html)). Quote: "Uses a script to provide a custom score for returned documents.

The script_score query is useful if, for example, a scoring function is expensive and you only need to calculate the score of a filtered set of documents."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if this is compatible with the "post-filter" option? From what I saw, even though the query in post-filter returns a score, the filtering option won't allow it to be considered at last and only the first score is used.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with compatible? As you mentioned, the `post_filter` does not contribute to the score, so I don't think you need it at all.

Comment: Indeed, I have tried your solution with the Script score query and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!